# Java crash when exit application: A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Tags: java, crash, exit, native-code

I have a Java application to drive a motor. The driver of the motor has been written in C++ with the Microsoft Visual Studio. I import (native code) this dll. The Java application runs without problems. I can start and stop the motor. 
But when I close this application, it crashes in the native code (motor driver).

I asked the furnisher of this motor. They told me, in the Microsoft environment (Visual Studio) the motor driver runs without problems. They said, there is no error. But they never tested the driver with a Java application.

I tried to suppress the error using the Exception and Error class. But it didn't work.

Question: Is it possible to suppress this error message?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_UNCAUGHT_CXX_EXCEPTION (0xe06d7363) at pc=0x7c812afb, pid=2180, tid=660
#
# JRE version: 6.0_37-b06
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.12-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [kernel32.dll+0x12afb]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x02ec8800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=660, stack(0x03280000,0x032d0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xe06d7363, ExceptionInformation=0x19930520 0x032cee88 0x0425be4c 

Registers:
EAX=0x032cedf0, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x0427eb1c
ESP=0x032cedec, EBP=0x032cee40, ESI=0x032cee78, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x7c812afb, EFLAGS=0x00000206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x032cedec)
0x032cedec:   0464dab8 e06d7363 00000001 00000000
0x032cedfc:   7c812afb 00000003 19930520 032cee88
0x032cee0c:   0425be4c 00000008 032cee2c 040d9e0a
0x032cee1c:   0427eb1c 00000000 0010f29c 00000000
0x032cee2c:   032cee58 040da3f8 040da418 5f210f53
0x032cee3c:   00000000 032cee78 041b873d e06d7363
0x032cee4c:   00000001 00000003 032cee6c e06d7363
0x032cee5c:   00000001 00000000 00000000 00000003 

Instructions: (pc=0x7c812afb)
0x7c812adb:   f9 0f 0f 87 6d 1e 03 00 85 c9 89 4d c0 74 07 57
0x7c812aeb:   8d 7d c4 f3 a5 5f 8d 45 b0 50 ff 15 10 15 80 7c
0x7c812afb:   5e c9 c2 10 00 85 ff 0f 8e 36 93 ff ff 8b 55 fc
0x7c812b0b:   89 55 0c 0f b7 16 8b 7d f8 8a 14 3a 88 11 8b 78 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x032cedf0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x02ec8800
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x0427eb1c is an unknown value
ESP=0x032cedec is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x02ec8800
EBP=0x032cee40 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x02ec8800
ESI=0x032cee78 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x02ec8800
EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x03280000,0x032d0000],  sp=0x032cedec,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [kernel32.dll+0x12afb]  RaiseException+0x52
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x26873d]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x1705da]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x17ec0d]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x1564f1]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x146bca]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x137714]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x12d5e8]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x12fbb2]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x106e38]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x107b8b]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0xcfbb8]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0xd2e7b]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x106e38]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x43268]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x39afb]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x106e38]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x102b3]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x4f5b]
C  [EposCmd.dll+0x5125]
C  [MaxonMotor.dll+0x15fb]
j  finaltest.MaxonMotor.close()Z+8
j  finaltest.FrameGWF$1.windowClosing(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+87
j  java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+8
j  java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+68
j  javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.Window.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+69
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+573
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+65
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb7cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18d3d1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb84d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xbbf84]
C  [java.dll+0x102f]  Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2Ljava_security_AccessControlContext_2+0x17
J  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb7cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18d3d1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb84d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xbbf84]
C  [java.dll+0x102f]  Java_java_security_AccessController_doPrivileged__Ljava_security_PrivilegedAction_2Ljava_security_AccessControlContext_2+0x17
J  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb7cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18d3d1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb971]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfb9cb]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb5e99]
V  [jvm.dll+0x119ab4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x14209c]
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x9565]  endthreadex+0xa0
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]  GetModuleFileNameA+0x1ba

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  finaltest.MaxonMotorCmd.closeAllDevices()Z+0
j  finaltest.MaxonMotor.close()Z+8
j  finaltest.FrameGWF$1.windowClosing(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+87
j  java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+8
j  java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+68
j  javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Ljava/awt/event/WindowEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.Window.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+69
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+573
j  java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+42
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+65
j  java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+2
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+41
j  java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Ljava/awt/EventQueue;Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+12
j  java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11
j  java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+73
J  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)Z
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+30
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x003b6c00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=2816, stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]
  0x02faf000 JavaThread "Thread-6" [_thread_blocked, id=1792, stack(0x04980000,0x049d0000)]
  0x02fd8400 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1676, stack(0x03ef0000,0x03f40000)]
  0x02f75800 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3844, stack(0x03ea0000,0x03ef0000)]
  0x02eb7400 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=1400, stack(0x03a60000,0x03ab0000)]
  0x02f3e400 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2528, stack(0x037c0000,0x03810000)]
=>0x02ec8800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=660, stack(0x03280000,0x032d0000)]
  0x02b7bc00 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2824, stack(0x031a0000,0x031f0000)]
  0x02b7a800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=1516, stack(0x03150000,0x031a0000)]
  0x02b79800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=296, stack(0x03100000,0x03150000)]
  0x02b61c00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3988, stack(0x02dd0000,0x02e20000)]
  0x02b53000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1960, stack(0x02d80000,0x02dd0000)]
  0x02b51800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2148, stack(0x02d30000,0x02d80000)]
  0x02b50400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3644, stack(0x02ce0000,0x02d30000)]
  0x02b4b800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1120, stack(0x02c90000,0x02ce0000)]
  0x02b46c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2820, stack(0x02c40000,0x02c90000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02b0a800 VMThread [stack: 0x02bf0000,0x02c40000] [id=2400]
  0x02b63c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02e20000,0x02e70000] [id=1396]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 5888K, used 69K [0x22990000, 0x22ff0000, 0x27ee0000)
  eden space 5248K,   1% used [0x22990000, 0x229a16e0, 0x22eb0000)
  from space 640K,   0% used [0x22eb0000, 0x22eb0000, 0x22f50000)
  to   space 640K,   0% used [0x22f50000, 0x22f50000, 0x22ff0000)
 tenured generation   total 12992K, used 7794K [0x27ee0000, 0x28b90000, 0x32990000)
   the space 12992K,  59% used [0x27ee0000, 0x2867cad8, 0x2867cc00, 0x28b90000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2179K [0x32990000, 0x33590000, 0x36990000)
   the space 12288K,  17% used [0x32990000, 0x32bb0ee0, 0x32bb1000, 0x33590000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x36990000, 0x36ec0500, 0x36ec0600, 0x37390000)
    rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x37390000, 0x37a2bd40, 0x37a2be00, 0x37f90000)

Code Cache  [0x00910000, 0x00a20000, 0x02910000)
 total_blobs=649 nmethods=432 adapters=153 free_code_cache=32450688 largest_free_block=320

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00425000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c910000 - 0x7c9c9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c908000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77e4a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e50000 - 0x77ee3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fc0000 - 0x77fd1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e360000 - 0x7e3f1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77ef0000 - 0x77f39000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76330000 - 0x7634d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x62e10000 - 0x62e19000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\LPK.DLL
0x75790000 - 0x757fb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USP10.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6daa0000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76af0000 - 0x76b1e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14c000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x72f70000 - 0x72f96000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x77be0000 - 0x77c38000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x774b0000 - 0x775ee000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x773a0000 - 0x774a3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f40000 - 0x77fb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x5b0f0000 - 0x5b128000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x746a0000 - 0x746ec000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x75250000 - 0x7527e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x7e670000 - 0x7ee91000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
0x6d230000 - 0x6d27f000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10013000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\btmmhook.dll
0x6d600000 - 0x6d613000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x71a10000 - 0x71a27000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71a00000 - 0x71a08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x6d620000 - 0x6d629000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x03520000 - 0x0352f000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\ownWinSys.dll
0x035b0000 - 0x035bc000     C:\Programme\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\btkeyind.dll
0x03230000 - 0x03246000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\javaxcomm.dll
0x03f40000 - 0x03f4e000     C:\Code\Java\Programme\FinalTest\MaxonMotor.dll
0x03f50000 - 0x042db000     C:\Code\Java\Programme\FinalTest\EposCmd.dll
0x76320000 - 0x76325000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x76350000 - 0x7639a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMDLG32.dll
0x770f0000 - 0x7717b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x61880000 - 0x618ba000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEACC.dll
0x4eba0000 - 0x4ed4b000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6002.22791_x-ww_c8dff154\gdiplus.dll
0x77bd0000 - 0x77bd8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d440000 - 0x6d465000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\jpeg.dll
0x04730000 - 0x04762000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ftd2xx.dll
0x778f0000 - 0x779e4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76c1e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINTRUST.dll
0x77a50000 - 0x77ae6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77af0000 - 0x77b02000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x76c50000 - 0x76c78000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
0x6d1a0000 - 0x6d1c3000     C:\Programme\Java\jre6\bin\dcpr.dll
0x76bb0000 - 0x76bbb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=C:\Code\Java\Programme\FinalTest;C:\Code\Java\Programme\FinalTest -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
java_command: finaltest.FrameGWF
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Programme/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Programme/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Programme/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\jet7.6-pro\bin;C:\Programme\ExcelsiorJET\bin;C:\Programme\WinAVR-20080610\bin;C:\Programme\WinAVR-20080610\utils\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Programme\Intel\DMIX;C:\Programme\Gemeinsame Dateien\Roxio Shared\DLLShared;c:\Programme\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Programme\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
USERNAME=Peloso
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 2079984k(1194376k free), swap 4022172k(3230168k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.12-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_37-b06), built on Sep 24 2012 12:44:35 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Thu Oct 25 14:59:01 2012
elapsed time: 14 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to suppress this, no. There's really not a good way of handling it clean because it is happening outside of your code. It could be a variety of things, such as out of date driver files, hardware incompatibilities, etc.

There are some insights in the stack trace though. The top of the stack says

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  finaltest.MaxonMotorCmd.closeAllDevices()Z+0
j  finaltest.MaxonMotor.close()Z+8
```

So it looks like the `closeAllDevices` method is causing this to happen. You should go through that method and make sure you are properly stopping the device and gracefully shutting it down.

Note that this is happening on the event dispatch thread as well (as indicated by the => in the thread list 
`=>0x02ec8800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=660, stack(0x03280000,0x032d0000)]`). Generally you don't want to be doing any heavy lifting (such as shutting down a motor) from the EDT.

Comment: I resolved this problem. I created a new thread, which open the resoures of the motor driver (native) and when the program is closed, it close the driver. If this two operations (open and close) are programmed in the same thread, it works. Thank you.